# Can I create "groups" in Excel histograms by adding spaces between specific bars?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I was hoping to create three visual groups in an excel histogram. More specifically, I was hoping to add a bit of space between the bar for 90% and 100%, and a bit of space between the 100% and 110% bar. (See link below). The idea is to visually group the data beyond the bins of Excel, so it's very clear that there's one "subgroup" of bins below 100%, then the subgroup at 100%, then a subgroup above 100%.

[Here's a link to the histogram picture and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6YN4.png)

If it's unclear what I'm asking let me know and I'll try to clarify further!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done by skipping a line between each bin category:

[image]

Comment: Excellent!! That's exactly what I was going for! Thank you!!! (I'll accept it as soon as it'll let me!)

Comment: Note that this will cause problems if someone assumes the X axis increases linearly and tries to interpolate values for 95% or 105%.